# Adminer or mysql error: no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, windows-10, database-connection

I have been trying to set up wordpress.org using localbyflywheel, but when I open Adminer I keep getting this error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it, what can I do to solve this error?

I am running MySQL on the same machine I installed Wordpress and I'm using Local by Flywheel instead of MAMP as the development environment. The MySQL service is up. Do I need to change anything in the config file?

Added info from comments

TCP 0.0.0.0:135 TCP 0.0.0.0:445 TCP 0.0.0.0:1801 TCP 0.0.0.0:2103 0.0.0.0:0 TCP 0.0.0.0:2105 0.0.0.0:0 TCP 0.0.0.0:2107 0.0.0.0:0 TCP 0.0.0.0:2869 0.0.0.0:0 TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 TCP 0.0.0.0:5040 TCP 0.0.0.0:5357 TCP 0.0.0.0:12666 TCP 0.0.0.0:49664 TCP 0.0.0.0:49665 TCP 0.0.0.0:49666 TCP 0.0.0.0:49667 TCP 0.0.0.0:49668 TCP 0.0.0.0:49677 TCP 0.0.0.0:49678 TCP 0.0.0.0:49896 TCP 127.0.0.1:4001 TCP 127.0.0.1:5354 TCP 127.0.0.1:16920

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ6hj.png)

[Active connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vhNo.png)

Comment: That is Windows message for _"Connection refused"_ and means that nothing is listening on the database address you gave. Therefore: either the database server didn't start or is listening on another IP address (usually only the loopback address `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Alright, thank you. So what steps can i take to check whether the database server isn't started or its an IP address issue? I really need your help because I don't know much about network connection troubleshooting

Comment: Add more information to your question: are you running MySQL on the same machine where you installed wordpress? Is the MySQL service up (look for the program `services.msc`)? Look for MySQL's config file (`my.cnf`).

Comment: Yes, I am running MySQL on the same machine I installed Wordpress and I'm using Local by Flywheel instead of MAMP as the development environment. The MySQL service is up. Do I need to change anything in the config file?

Comment: So run `netstat -a -n` and add the lines with `LISTENING` to your question. You should also check your firewall settings.

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:135
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1801
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2103  0.0.0.0:0
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2105  0.0.0.0:0
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2107   0.0.0.0:0
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869   0.0.0.0:0   
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12666  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664      
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666 TCP    0.0.0.0:49667 
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49677
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49678
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49896
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4001    
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354        
  TCP    127.0.0.1:16920

Comment: Add this data to your **question**, together with the rest of information you provided in comments (edit the question). The remaining StackExchange won't read all comments.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a firewall problem. You can disable the firewall temporarily and check if you can connect.

Since you MySQL runs on port `3306` of all your IP addresses, try:

1. Connecting to your server using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as hostname. The default firewall config should not block communication over the loopback device.
2. If that fails add a firewall rule that allows connections to port `3306` from hosts on the `127.0.0.0/8` network and try again.